# Error connecting from React Native app to SIP server using react-native-jssip: "Handshake failed"

Tags: react-native, sip, opensips, jssip

[what i get when try to connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZkWJ.jpg)
[@xml/network_security_config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdetU.jpg).
I am trying to establish a connection from my React Native app to a SIP server using the react-native-jssip library (or any other library if recommended).

However, I am encountering the following error:

```
error: +32s {"isTrusted": false, "message": "Handshake failed"}.
Library Used: react-native-jssip (or specify if using another library)
Error Message: {"isTrusted": false, "message": "Handshake failed"}
Network Security Configuration: I have added the necessary configurations in @xml/network_security_config and included the certificate.
Installed the react-native-jssip library.
Configured the SIP server details.
Added network security configurations and included the certificate.
Implemented the connection logic.
when I disabled security from the server it connected successfully.
```